# Django Admin Page execute javascript on Custom Action Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-admin

I'm trying to add a custom button in each row next to a user to the django admin page which makes it easier for the admin to click the button and generate a password reset link for a particular user rather than navigate to the hidden `actions` section of the django admin page.

Something like this - https://hakibenita.com/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin

Following is the code I've implemented and it works and navigates to a new page with the correct `reset-password` request and the `reset_password()` method executes with a link being sent to the user.

However, when I click the button, I would like to send an AJAX `GET` request to the same url as above and just a show an alert to the admin on request completion instead of navigating to a new page. Currently I'm unable to run the javascript code using the `format_html` method in Django (see code below)

```py
class UserAdmin(Admin.modelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'custom_actions')

    form = forms.UserAdminForm
  
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            url(
                r'reset-password/(?P<user_id>.+)',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.reset-password),
                name='reset-password',
            ),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls

    def custom_actions(self, obj):
            user = user_model.User.get(user_id=obj.id)
            password_reset_url = reverse('admin:reset-password', args=[user.id])
            return mark_safe(format_html(
                f'<a class="button" onclick="parent.location=\'{password_reset_url}\'" >Reset Password</a>&nbsp;'
    custom_actions.short_description = 'Custom Actions'
    custom_actions.allow_tags = True


    def reset_password(self, request, password_reset_id):
        password_reset.send_password_reset_link(password_reset_id=password_reset_id)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Below is the HTML/JS code that I was testing for the behavior I want on the page and works, I was hoping to the stitch the same into the above Django code but Django cannot execute and just shows the script as a string on the admin page.

```
<button id='jax' class="button">AJAX</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jax").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "my-dynamic-url",
        timeout:10,
        jsonp : "jsonp",
        success : function (response, textS, xhr) {
          console.log('oof')
          alert("Password reset link has been resent");
        },
        error : function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          if(textStatus==='timeout')
            alert("request timed out");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Is there a correct way to integrate the above javascript code on admin page on the click of the button?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing out on commas? From an example according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/):

```py
format_html("{} <b>{}</b> {}",
    mark_safe(some_html),
    some_text,
    some_other_text,
)
```

Maybe you should wrap `{password_reset_url}` in commas and see if that works.

If this does not solve your problem, elaborating on this will be helpful:

> Django cannot execute and just shows the script as a string on the admin page.

Which script are you referring to?

Comment: Yes I tried the above from the documentation before posting the question and kept getting `unexpected { in field name` error even with `{{` string formatting.
I'm referring to the script between `<script>` tag above. I would like to run the same when I click the button as can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/1vogsfqe/2/

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

Python:

```py
class UserAdmin(Admin.modelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'custom_actions')

    form = forms.UserAdminForm
  
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            url(
                r'reset-password/(?P<user_id>.+)',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.reset-password),
                name='reset-password',
            ),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls

    def custom_actions(self, obj):
            user = user_model.User.get(user_id=obj.id)
            password_reset_url = reverse('admin:reset-password', args=[user.id])
            return mark_safe(format_html(
                f'<a class="button" onclick="send_password_link(\'{password_reset_url}\'") >Reset Password</a>&nbsp;'
    custom_actions.short_description = 'Custom Actions'
    custom_actions.allow_tags = True


    def reset_password(self, request, password_reset_id):
        password_reset.send_password_reset_link(password_reset_id=password_reset_id)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

HTML:
This should be under `base-app/templates/your-app/change_list.html`

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} 
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'js/passwordReset.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Render the rest of the ChangeList view by calling block.super -->
{{ block.super }} 

{% endblock %}
```

Javascript:
This should be under `base-app/static/static/js/passwordReset.js`

```
function send_password_link(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert('Password Reset Sent');
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```